# Dummy implementation design pattern name

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming

To avoid NullPointerExceptions I find it useful to provide an immutable dummy implementation of an interface together with the interface. Like this:

```
public interface Action {

  void perform();

  public static final Action dummy = new Action() {
    public void perform() { 
      /*nothing*/ 
    }
  };

}
```

`Action.dummy` can then be used instead of the evil `null`.

Is there a name for this design pattern?

Comment: Program Doesn't Work and I Don't Know Why Pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) (provided by M. Fowler if I remember correctly).

Here is a chapter [Introduce Null Object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-null-object) from Fowler's Refactoring book.

Comment: Yes, Fowler popularized this one in various publications, altho he called it a SpecialCase in PoEAA, which I like even better. Typically a business app will find there is actually useful behavior that goes with an object wanting to be null, if you look for it too.

Comment: I find "SpecialCase" pretty meaningless. A special case could be everything and nothing, whereas "Null Object" is more meaningful.